# Cannot find 'present' in scope for Flutter plugin

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-plugin

Currently I am trying to do a plugin to integrate third party native SDK with Flutter and I'm not really familiar with Swift.

In the third party SDK, there is a line of code that need to be implemented:

`present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

When I tried to run, there's an error `cannot find 'present' in scope`.

I tried to use `self.present` but still didn't work.

Comment: Have you had any success in finding a solution?

Comment: I still don't have the solution @MilanCiganović

Comment: Still no solution?

Comment: I've abandoned this project unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You can try use the rootViewController and show it in your custom view.

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(...)
```